# Nodemailer works on local PC, but not on server

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer, linode

I want to send emails via Gmail (OAuth) from a node.js application with nodemailer. It works perfectly fine on my PC, but if I try it from my Linode server nothing happens. I don't get an error, it just times out after a few minutes.
Firewall is disabled and because the code works on my local machine, I don't know where to start.
Maybe someone knows where to start and help me with this issue.

**EDIT:** You have to contact Linode Support to lift SMTP restrictions :)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I've also had issues sending mails from live servers using nodemailer.
I was able to send mails using this block of code:

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer")
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({sendmail: true}, {
        from: "no-reply@your-server.com",
        to: "recipient@mail.com",
        subject: "subject"
    })
    var contact;
        transporter.sendMail({html: "<p>mail sent</p>"}, (error, info) => {
        if(error){
                console.log(error)
        }
        else {
                console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        }
})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I contacted Linode support, and they told me that they have SMTP restrictions for new accounts.

Comment: I'm also use same linode account. @Julian is it working after enable SMTP port for linode

Comment: @Pragnesh Yes that was the fix. You have to contact Linode support for that.

Comment: Yes, working Thanks man